# Pig: which jar to register for using REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL method?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to use the built in method REGEX_EXTRACT and REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL methods of Pig.  Which jar should i include for this?  Any links?

Comment: I tried pig-0.7.0+9-core.jar, but that doesnt seem to have it.  I am getting an error "Could not resolve REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions are named RegexExtract(...)/RegexExtractAll() in 0.7 and
case sensitivity matters

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  col1 = FOREACH test GENERATE RegexExtractAll($0, ',');

Comment: i see the methods as defined as you say in the API page (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/), strange why mine is throwing an error.  So i'll accept your answer.  thanks.

Comment: You need to get org.apache.pig.piggybank.* loaded somehow

Comment: register piggybank.jar. You can get piggybank.jar in contrib/piggybank

Answer (score 1):

And they are builtin in [0.9](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/func.html#regex-extract-all) now.